# Setting up Django on Google App Engine for DataStore

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How do I setup Django on Google App Engine to use DataStore? I did a bunch of searches and some seemed to point to something called django-nonrel. But I couldn't find anything that looked like a definitive guide up-to-date (dated around 2012-2013).

Answer (score 4):

The [djangae](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae) project seems to be what you're looking for. From their [documentation](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> Djangae (jan-gee) is a Django app that allows you to run Django
>   applications on Google App Engine, including (if you want to) using
>   Django's models with the App Engine Datastore as the underlying
>   database.

It has a Database backend that supports AppEngine's Datastore, so you can use Django's ORM. In addition to Django's default fields, a number of other field types are added in the project.

You should consider the [list of limitations](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db_backend/#what-cant-it-do) carefully though.